# What's the most logical way to store this structured information in PHP?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to dynamically generate an HTML list based on the number of options that a particular application has.

An item in the list should take the following form:

```
       <li>
           <a href="$HREF" title="$LINK_TITLE">
               <i class="$ICON_CLASS"></i> $OPTION_NAME
           </a>
       </li>
```

Where for each "option" in the application, there are four strings associated with it: `href`, `link_title`, `icon-class`, and `option_name`.

Now if I were programming in C, I'd probably use a struct to hold this information. In PHP though, I'm not so sure. What's the most logical way for me to store these four fields for each option? Ideally, I'm trying to set it up so that I can generate the list with a straightforward for-loop.

What's the best practice for this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just use an associative array:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    "href"=>"value",
    "link_title"=>"value",
    "icon_class"=>"value",
    "option_name"=>"value"
  ),
  array(
    "href"=>"value",
    "link_title"=>"value",
    "icon_class"=>"value",
    "option_name"=>"value"
  ),
);
```

Then you can use a `foreach` loop over the main array, and get the associative indexes for your variables.

Alternatively, if you prefer OOP, you can try something like this:

```
class Option {
    private $href="";
    private $link_title="";
    private $icon_class="";
    private $option_name="";
    public function __construct($a,$b,$c,$d) {
        $this->href = $a;
        $this->link_title = $b;
        $this->icon_class = $c;
        $this->option_name = $d;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return "<li><a href=\"".$this->href."\" title=\"".$this->link_title."\">"
           ."<i class=\"".$this->icon_class."\"></i> ".$this->option_name."</a></li>";
    }
}
$array = array(
    new Option("href","title","class","name"),
    new Option("href","title","class","name")
);
echo implode("\n",$array);
```

Comment: That toString() method in the OOP suggestion seems perfect. What does the '__' mean before it though?

Comment: The double-underscore is what marks it as a magic method, like the `__construct` function.

Answer (score 6):

multi dimensional array:

```
array(
    'option' => array('href' => 'url', 'title' => 'title', 'icon' => 'icon'), 
    'option' => array('href' => 'url', 'title' => 'title', 'icon' => 'icon')
);
```

Comment: Interesting. So if I wanted to loop over this, I would access it as $array_name[i]['href']?

Comment: that is right or you can do a loop like: `foreach($varname as $row)` then you can do `$row['url']` skipping the `$i`

Answer (score 3):

You can either use a class:

```
class MyOption {
    public $href;
    public $link_title;
    public $icon_class;
    public $option_name;
}
$op = MyOption();
$op->href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Or an array:

```
$op = array(
    'href'        => "http://www.google.com";
    'link_title'  => "Google";
    'icon_class'  => "image";
    'option_name' => "name";
);
echo $op['icon_class'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the OOP way, you can also use an object:

```
<?php
    class link {
        public $href;
        public $title;
        public $icon;
        public $option;
        public function __construct($href, $title, $icon, $option) {
            $this->href = $href;
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->icon = $icon;
            $this->option = $option;
        }
    }

    $links = array();
    $links[] = new link('http://www.google.com', 'Google', 'google.png', 'google_option');

    foreach ($links as $link) {
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?=$link->href?>" title="<?=$link->title?>">
                    <i class="<?=$link->icon?>"></i> <?=$link->option?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: [In early stages of Internet, developers were forced to work with poor, dry, functional, horrific languages. Everything had to be done through austere functions and operators. There was no objects. No interfaces. No dependency injection. For example, to make something as simple as an addition, our dads had to write: 1+1. Yeah, really. Hopefuly now, we have PHP 5.3 and its solid OOP implementation. SimplePHPEasyPlus lets you make this addition in a more fashionable way, using real OOP. It is fast, simple, flexible and tested.](https://github.com/Herzult/SimplePHPEasyPlus)

Comment: @YourCommonSense A very entertaining project! :D I simply implied that *if* OP wants to do this with objects, this is a way of doing it. Personally I prefer objects for future proofing my code. Don't get me wrong, I completely get your point, and to some degree, I agree, however the reason that *I* prefer objects is that if I suddenly need to add a method to get something custom (*no code is ever fully done, right?*) it makes the job very easy (eg. `$link->GetAbsoluteURL()`).

Answer (score 0):

There are several good ways, depending on the size of the list and what you want to do with it.

Using just arrays:

```
$links = array();
$links[] = array('href'=>$href, 'title'=>$title, 'class'=>$class, 'name'=>$name);
$links[] = array('href'=>$href2, 'title'=>$title2, 'class'=>$class2, 'name'=>$name2);

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo "<li>
           <a href=\"{$link['href']}\" title=\"{$link['title']}\">
               <i class=\"{$link['class']}\"></i> {$link['name']}
           </a>
          </li>";
}
```

It's also possible to construct objects for this case and store the objects in an array:

```
class linkClass {
    public $href;
    public $title;
    public $class;
    public $name;

    function __construct($href, $title, $class, $name) {
        $this->href = $href;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function listItem() {
        return "<li>
                  <a href=\"{$this->href}\" title=\"{$this->title}\">
                    <i class=\"{$this->class}\"></i> $this->name}
                  </a>
                </li>";
    }
}

$array_of_link_objects = array();
$array_of_link_objects[] = new link($href, $title, $class, $name);
$array_of_link_objects[] = new link($href2, $title2, $class2, $name2);

foreach ($array_of_link_objects as $link_object) {
    echo $link_object->listItem();
}
```

For future reference, if you ever need to store a LARGE number of items without using a hash table, try looking at the splFixedArray documentation on php.net. It only allows for numeric keys though, so $spl_object['href'] won't work. The memory savings are HUGE for large splFixedArrays though. For your case, I might say try the object approach if you're going to be using these links in many different files so that code maintenance is easy later. If it's isolated to one file and you're not using 100k links (since arrays are TERRIBLE about memory in PHP), you'd be fine with just multi-dimensional arrays.